# Vue returns both observer and array

Tags: arrays, vue.js, observers

I'm currently working on a private chatroom.
i started two browser from which one in incognito
when i send a message from browser window one i console.log the chats array but it's an vue observer object.
when i send a message from browser window 2 i console.log the same chats array, but it tels me it's an array
the first browser window gives an error this.chats.push is not a function
the second browser window accepts the function and saves the message and adds it to the chats array.

Can anybody explain to me why it is doing that?
Just curious

```js
<template>
    <div class="card card-default chat-box">
        <div class="card-header">
            <b :class="{'text-danger':isBlocked}">
                {{friend.first_name}}
                <span v-if="isBlocked">(Blocked)</span>
            </b>

            <!--      Close button      -->
            <a href="" @click.prevent="close">
                <font-awesome-icon icon="times" class="float-right"/>
            </a>
            <!--      Close button ends here      -->

            <!--       Options     -->
            <div class="dropdown float-right">
                <b-dropdown variant="link" no-caret toggle-class="text-decoration-none">
                    <template v-slot:button-content>
                        <font-awesome-icon icon="ellipsis-v"/>
                    </template>
                    <b-dropdown-item href="" @click.prevent="block" v-if="!isBlocked">Block</b-dropdown-item>
                    <b-dropdown-item href="" @click.prevent="unblock" v-if="isBlocked">Unblock</b-dropdown-item>
                    <b-dropdown-item href="" @click.prevent="clear">Clear</b-dropdown-item>
                    <b-dropdown-divider></b-dropdown-divider>
                    <b-dropdown-item active>Active action</b-dropdown-item>
                    <b-dropdown-item disabled>Disabled action</b-dropdown-item>
                </b-dropdown>
            </div>
            <!--       Options Ends     -->
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" v-chat-scroll>
            <p class="card-text" :class="{'text-right': chat.type === false}" v-for="chat in chats" :key="chat.id">
                {{chat.message}}
            </p>
        </div>
        <form class="card-footer" @submit.prevent="send">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Write your message"
                       :disabled="isBlocked" v-model="message"
                >
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {faIcons} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
    import {DropDownButtonPlugin} from "@syncfusion/ej2-vue-splitbuttons";

    Vue.use(DropDownButtonPlugin);

    export default {
        props: ['friend'],
        computed: {
            queen() {
                return faIcons;
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                chats: [],
                message: null,
                isBlocked: false
            }
        },
        methods: {
            send() {
                if (this.message) {
                    this.pushToChats(this.message);
                    axios.post('/dashboard/chats/messages/store', {
                        session_id: this.friend.session.id,
                        message: this.message,
                        to_user_id: this.friend.id
                    });
                    this.message = null;
                }
            },
            pushToChats(message) {
                // this.getAllMessages();
                console.log(this.chats);
                console.log(typeof this.chats);
                this.chats.push({message: message, type: false, send_at: 'Just Now'});
            },
            close() {
                this.$emit('close');
            },
            clear() {
                this.chats = [];
            },
            block() {
                this.isBlocked = true
            },
            unblock() {
                this.isBlocked = false;
            },
            getAllMessages() {
                axios.post(`/dashboard/chats/session/${this.friend.session.id}`)
                    .then(res => this.chats = res.data
                    );
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.getAllMessages();

            Echo.private(`Chat.${this.friend.session.id}`).listen('PrivateChatEvent', (e) => {
                this.chats.push({message: e.content, type: true, send_at: 'Just Now'})
            });
        },
        name: "MessageComponent"
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .chat-box {
        height: 400px;
    }

    .card-body {
        overflow-y: scroll
    }
</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: `chats` is always an array except possibly for the assignment you do inside `getAllMessages`; can you confirm that `res.data` is also an array?

Comment: The observer is a wrapper that's ignored when rendering and used to track changes. It's Vue's reactivity. If you don't want to see it, simply spread: `console.log([...yourArray])`